# How to return a new type from Web API post?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to come up with a way to post to a Web API controller with one object but have a different, processed, object return. None of the methods I've been able to find have solved the issue.

Here's my method in my MVC project that posts to my Web API project

```
public dynamic PostStuff<X>(string action, X request)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                var task = client.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri("host/api/somecontroller/post, request);
                task.Wait();
                var response = task.Result;

                return response;

            }

        }
```

This is my Web API controller code

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] FooObject foo)
    {
        var res =  Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
            new ValidationResponse<FooObject>
            {
                ID = new Random().Next(1000, 1000000),
                Content =
                    new List<IContent>()
                    {
                        {
                            new Content()
                            {
                                Name = "TheContent",
                                Type = "SomeType",
                                Value = "This is some content for the page : " + foo.Bar
                            }
                        }
                    },
                Product = new ProductFoo(),
                Validated = true
            });
        return res;
    }
}
```

When I put a break in my WebAPI controller code, the res variable is correctly created. Once the processing goes back to the PostStuff method, all I get is a StreamResponse with no trace of the ValidationResponse object created in the Web API controller. There are no errors but I can't use anything in the response beyond that the post succeeded. How can I extract the ValidationResponse from my posting method?

Comment: can't you convert that `response` into a `HttpResponseMessage` ?

Comment: You should use `await` instead of `.Wait()`.

Comment: It's coming back as an HttpResponseMessage already. Even if I return a custom type from the controller, PostAsJsonAsync always returns a HttpResponseMessage which does not contain the data I need. Is there something else I can use to accomplish the post->return new type->use it on my page task?

Comment: Also, I get a message stating HttpResponseMessage is not awaitable if I try to use await vs task.Wait();

Answer (score 0):

I have built myself this *generic function* as a helper for POSTing to `Web API`

Usage

```
var result = PostAsync<MyDataType, MyResultType>("http://...", MyData)
```

Function

```
public async Task<U> PostAsync<T, U>(string url, T model)
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler))
    {
        var result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(url, model);

        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode == false)
        {
            string message = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            throw new Exception(message);
        }
        else
        {
            return await result.Content.ReadAsAsync<U>();
        }
    }
}
```

And `HttpClientHandler` configured for Windows Auth

```
protected HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { PreAuthenticate = true, UseDefaultCredentials = true };
```

Comment: What is in your httpHandler variable? I've tried to use this code and it never gets to the IsSuccessStatusCode condition test. Just returns right out of the result = await line. Weird.

Comment: It's a HttpClientHandler that I'm configuring for Windows Auth,  `HttpClientHandler httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler() { PreAuthenticate = true, UseDefaultCredentials = true };`

Comment: Still not getting what I'm wanting. The response object I get back every time looks something like this:

Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
    AsyncState: null
    CancellationPending: false
    CreationOptions: None
    Exception: null
    Id: 1
    Result: null
    Status: WaitingForActivation

Comment: @HapiDjus That is the result of the Task type. You'll need to await or get the result of ReadAsStringAsync().